# How do I test several variables against a value and change them based on the outcome in C?

Tags: c, syntax

There are three variables that need to be tested against the same value (var1 or var2 or var3 > 255). If the comparison is true for any of them, the corresponding variable's value needs to be set to 255. Here's what i came up with:

```
if (r > 255)
    r = 255;
if (g > 255)
    g = 255;
if (b > 255)
    b = 255;
```

and

```
r += (r > 255) * (255 - r);
g += (g > 255) * (255 - g);
b += (b > 255) * (255 - b);
```

Since these are quite similar, so I was wondering if there's a way to shorten this code somehow.

Comment: But why would you shorten a very readable and understable code that trims the value up to 255?

Comment: The first example is short and clear. In the second it is unclear what is happening.

Comment: Sometimes in easy repetitive code like that I will put `if (r > 255) r = 255;` all on a single line, which can make other nearby code more readable.

Comment: Would `r &= 0xFF; g &= 0xFF; b &= 0xFF;` be acceptable or does that change the algorithm too much?

Comment: @KamilCuk Just trying to learn new tricks.

Comment: @Lundin Great suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since these are quite similar, so I was wondering if there's a way to shorten this code somehow.

You could *shorten this code somehow* by using a macro:

```
#define LIMIT(v) if (v > 255) v = 255
LIMIT(r);
LIMIT(g);
LIMIT(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function to do this:

```
void saturate(int *p)
{
    if(*p > 255)
        *p = 255;
}
```

Then you could put your variables in an array and loop over that:

```
int colors[3];

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(colors)/sizeof(colors[0]); i++)
    saturate(&colors[i]);
```